# Destroy an iScroll object

Tags: jquery, iscroll4

I create an iScroll object:

```
this.bodyScroll = new IScroll('body', {
                scrollbars: true
            });
```

The scroller appears in the DOM.

The I try to destory it:

```
this.bodyScroll.destroy();
```

But the scroller is still visiable and in the DOM. Then when I create the iScroll object again, I now have 2 scrollers in the DOM. How do I destroy and remove from DOM?

Answer (score 2):

iScroll has a method for that: [`object.destroy()`](https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll#destroy)

```
var scroll_bar = new IScroll('body', {
       scrollbars: true
});

// and when you want to remove it:
scroll_bar.destroy();
```